# Use the fact that $u(t)\cdot u'(t)=0$ for $u\in\mathcal{S}^2$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

If for all $t$, $u(t)$ is a point on the unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^2 \subset\mathbb{R}^3$, $u'(t)$ is orthogonal to $u(t)$, because $u'(t)$ is in the tangent plane of the sphere.

I have large expressions that would simplify greatly if I knew how to have *Mathematica* use that property. But I fail to manage.

For example, how to have `u[t].u'[t]` return `0` in the following?

```
u[t_] = Through[{u1, u2, u3}[t]];
Simplify[u[t].u'[t], Assumptions -> Norm[u[t]] == 1]
Simplify[u[t].u'[t], Element[u[t], Sphere[]]]
(* both return u1[t] u1'[t] + u2[t] u2'[t] + u3[t] u3'[t] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

We had to manual `D` the condition :)

```
u[t_] = Through[{u1, u2, u3}[t]];
Simplify[u[t].u'[t], Assumptions -> D[u[t].u[t] == 1, t]]
```